# std::tuple vs std::array as items of a std::vector

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, vector, tuples

I have this case:

```
std::vector<4_integers> v;
```

---

What would fit best here?

**`std::tuple` solution:**

```
std::vector<std::tuple<int,int,int,int>> v;
```

---

**`std::array` solution:**

```
std::vector<std::array<int,4>> v;
```

and why?

**EDIT (The use case):**

Sorry for not mentioning that before. I am going to use it as follow:

```
for(const auto& item:v){
   some_function(item[0],item[1],item[2],item[3]); // or tuple equivalent 
}
```

Of course I need to keep them stored because computing the 4 integers is not a thing that I want to repeat again and again.

Comment: Both could be a solution to *some* problem... and now it all depends on *what* specific problem you're facing. Note that all problems are not equal, just as all solutions are not equal.

Comment: Depends on how you will use them.

Comment: use case added . thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For this specific case, I'd have to disagree with the comments. For homogeneous type containers - as is the case here (all `int`s) - `array` is superior.

When looking at the interface of [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) vs. [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array), it is very clear that the latter is a container (with iterators, e.g.), while the former is not. This means that the rest of the standard library will be much more naturally applicable to the latter.

If the types weren't homogeneous, there wouldn't be a question - it would have to be `std::tuple`.

Comment: You make a lot of assumptions about the OP's use case when he has not yet told us what problem he is trying to solve. For all we know, he may have thousands of `std::tuple`-based lines of code to interface with. Or the `int`s in the tuple  may actually come from individual template arguments which just happen to be equal in one particular case.

Comment: The types can be homogeneous by accident (which inspired me to answer)

Comment: Yes, you're both right - the answer assumes that the types are homogeneous with some significance. Good point.

Answer (score 4):

This depends a lot on the use case, but if the elements are somehow related, I would choose `array`. You can iterate over array and use std algorithms with them.

I usually think `tuple` as a substitute to something you could replace with a `struct` like:

```
struct fourIntegers{
  int int1;
  int int2;
  int int3;
  int int4;
};
```

Sometimes the `tuple` is just  more compact/clear than a new `struct`.