# Is it better to return a vector<int> or an int*?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I have a method which is supposed to return some integers. Those integers will be used after in a constructor. Since I am not very comfortable with pointers, I decided to use a vector as my return type so that later in the constructor of myObject I can use myVector[i] to access the different ints.

But my colleague says that a int* as a return type is better in this case because "if it's to return a container, then you'd better return a myObject type and instantiate it directly in the method".

So it seems that the use of a pointer is better in this case. Is it true? And then why?

EDIT: Ok, i'll try to detail it more down here.

Here is my class with three int attributes:

```
class MyClass{

public:
MyClass(int x, int y, int s);

private:
int coord_x;
int coord_y;
int size;
}
```

In another .cpp file, I have a method like this:

```
// FileWithMethod.cpp
vector<int> myMethod(){

// some code here
return my_vector;
}
```

my_vector has 3 int and always will because its elements will be used to instantiate a MyClass object in a second .cpp file.

The discussion here is whether the return type of myMethod() should be an int* or a vector. My colleague suggests an int* because "it is useless to implement this kind of structure (i.e. a method that returns parameters that will be used later in a constructor)". Why he says that, I don't know. He says that this structure is interesting if we use a pointer but if we use a container, then it is better to directly return a MyClass object instantiated with the 3 int. So he seems to be clearly against the idea of vector, probably in terms of memory allocation/management, and would prefer the use of an int* against a MyClass object.

And here I thought that the major asset of C++ was to get rid of the tricky pointers and to use them only when there is no other option or when the performance difference is non negligible.

I hope this clarifies a bit more the situation. Sorry for the vague explanation. It is not easy for me to estimate if the amount of details provided is enough to understand the problem when you are working on it and have no outside perspective :).

Thank you for your answers, they are already quite helpful!

Comment: I _think_ I almost see what you're getting at, but this question is pretty vague. Can you give code examples, and provide your chosen definition of "better"? For what it's worth, returning a vector is a good default position because it's simple and has no questions over data ownership, but it's not clear to me whether your colleague's suggestion breaks that, or just suggests a better way to populate the vector. Either way, there is no catch-all answer that can be safely given to this question as currently written; that is, **it depends**.

Comment: I guess what your colleague meant is that you construct the object in the function and return the object and not the cointainer (or an int*). The advantage of an container is you know how many elements are in it. If you only return and `int*` you don't know the numbers of elements.

Comment: vector<int> versus int** seems to be more appropriate question. int* is a pointer to an int whereas int** can point to multiple int variables which is more close a vector<int>

Comment: If you feel like need to use any of std::vector functions use vector, otherwise if you only want to access those integers and read them use pointer as it is more faster and efficient than using a class like vector for such a simple use.

Comment: In modern C++ raw pointers are considered to be a weak pointers. If you have raw pointer, then you do not own the object. When you return a bunch if integers from a function you transfer ownership to the callee. So int* is a bad choice here. It must be some container or it can be `std::unique_ptr<int[]>`. But pointer to array still is not a very good choice: how callee has to know it's size? So generally, if you need to return a bunch of objects, vector is a good choice.

Comment: @Shahriyar, using raw array is NOT faster and NOT more efficient, than using a vector. But it is much harder and more error prone.

Comment: @AlexeyGuseynov If you find pointers hard to understand leave c++ and write in c#.And yes it is more efficient specially when writing big programs like an mmo game server.

Comment: returning a `myObject` directly instead of the arguments for its constructor is problematic if later you may want to create a `myDerivedObject` for example.

Comment: @Shahriyar: They are harder to rationalise about and prove behaviours for. That is an objective fact. Doesn't matter how clever you are. There is no need to "leave C++", when using standard containers has been idiomatic and commonplace in C++ for at least the past twenty years. C++ is not C. And, no, it is not more efficient. If you're comparing dynamic vs non-dynamic allocation then fine, but be honest about it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Everything comes with a price.

Comment: @Shahriyar: Yes, and the price of abandoning vectors for manually-allocated dynamic arrays (your "pointers" - again, if you are instead comparing against non-dynamic allocation then state that and be honest about it) is high. Do you know what the associated benefit is? _There isn't one._

Comment: (Okay, if you're creating 5,000,000,000,000 ints and you don't need them zero-initialised, then _maybe_.)

Comment: @Shahriyar: If you're trying to say that adding the utility of `std::vector` over dynamic allocation has some sort of cost that manifests at run-time, there's nothing I can say other than that you are wrong :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit [vector::push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) As the source says 1) The new element is initialized as a copy of value.
2) value is moved into the new element.
Imagine you have just let's say 500 object of a class.why in the world you want to put a **copy** of them into a vector and allocate twice memory (I know the temp one will get freed as soon as you add it to vector) when you can use pointers and by pointers I include smart pointers so you don't have to worry about memory deallocating.

Comment: @Shahriyar: We've had `emplace_back` for half a decade. Before that, such a temporary was almost certain to be optimised out. That's arguably _less_ likely to be true for your manually-managed arrays!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your colleague's quotes I assume he is recommending returning the object you aim to instantiate instead of `vector`, not the `int*`. This means that if sole purpose of this return value is to be an input to the other object's constructor, why not construct the object in this function and skip the temporary structures.

In your example it would be:

```
MyClass myMethod(){    
    // some code here
    return MyClass{ /* my_vector values */ };
}
```

That said, returning pointer to array (which I assume you mean by `int*`) is probably not a good idea, because you would have to keep track of who is supposed to `delete` it later (after `MyClass`construction). In this regard standard containers are preferable.

If you do not want to use `vector` because of its minor performance impact (which you should consider living with anyway IMO) and cannot instantiate the target class in the method, maybe there is another way. I would use `tuple<int, int, int>` for example as a return value. It's very lightweight and easier to use than raw c-like array. It is not as easy to maintain if, for example, number of parameters change in the future.

Comment: The thing is that here we need to separate the methods like myMethod() (i.e. the ones which return future constructor parameters), the classes like MyClass (i.e. the ones whose constructors will use the return parameters of myMethod()) and the .cpp file which will use all of this. To make it short, we have .cpp files to store methods like myMethod(), .cpp files to store classes like MyClass, and a .cpp file to call the methods and instantiate the MyClass objects (like a "main.cpp" but without a main). So normally the instatiation occurs in the "main.cpp"-like file.

Comment: What my colleague says is "if sole purpose of this return value is to be an input to the other object's constructor, why not construct the object in this function and skip the temporary structures? It would be better but since we are instantiating the objects in the main-like file, you should not do it in the methods. Hence the use of int*"

Comment: @SoniaSeddiki maybe you would be interested in a `tuple` then? see my edit

Comment: Using a tuple would be nice, but then what is the difference between a `tuple<int, int, int>` and an `array<int, 3>`? I know I'm being picky here, but it is more for my personal culture than real performance concern this time. Hope you don't mind :)!

Comment: @SoniaSeddiki I don't see much difference between those two, to be honest. For example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35743470/stdtuple-vs-stdarray-as-items-of-a-stdvector) regards it in more semantic grounds. Choose whichever you feel better using ;)

Comment: Now that I think about it, I could totally use a `tuple` and replace the two first int by a Point since they are coordinates (the attributes of MyClass are a Point and an int). So a `tuple<Point, int>` might be more suitable to avoid further treatment in the constructor, don't you think?

Comment: @SoniaSeddiki I do believe it is clearer in terms of what this function returns and what its purpose is. It's important for the code to describe the intent of the programmer

Answer (score 1):

As you always return exactly 3 `int`s, a sufficiently small number, consider [`std::array<int, 3>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead.

It might be the most efficient and certainly the most restricted standard type.

Comment: I didn't know that the array type existed in C++ (thought it was replaced by vector). I will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: Both `std::vector` and `std::array` have their use cases. vector is meant to replace a dynamically sized array, and array is meant to replace a fixed size array.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, returning a standard container from a method or function is fine. Unless you already know that it will be a very intensively used function that does require low level optimization, rejecting that in early developpement stages looks to me as prematurate optimization.

As explained in comments by @LightnessRacesinOrbit, using a vector will add some overhead because of the dynamic allocation and initialization of data. If you really need such low level optimization, I would declare 3 variables in caller and pass them by reference. That way you have no risk of returning a dangling pointer, no problem of thread safety (could arise if you use a static array to avoid the dangling pointer problem) and no unnecessary dynamic allocation. Just use:

```
void myMethod(int& x, int& y, int& s) {
    ...
}
```

IMHO, directly returning a `MyClass` object could (depending on the general design) add unwanted dependances between modules.

Comment: I am not sure about the cost in performance here. We are working on computer vision. We have to analyze a 30 to 60 fps video stream and use those methods every frame. We aim to do multithreaded image treatment but it is currently not the case.